# How can I get the total amount of the items in the cart?

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing the function of cart. But I don't know how to add up the amount of cart. Currently, the value I chose is in the form of an array in the cart, and I need to find the sum of these values. The information of the item I chose is in the state of `InCart` as an array like this

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "실전! 스프링 부트와 JPA 활용1 - 웹 애플리케이션 개발",
      "provider": "김영한",
      "price": 88000,
      "image": "https://cdn.inflearn.com/public/courses/324119/course_cover/07c45106-3cfa-4dd6-93ed-a6449591831c/%E1%84%80%E1%85%B3%E1%84%85%E1%85%AE%E1%86%B8%205%20%E1%84%87%E1%85%A9%E1%86%A8%E1%84%89%E1%85%A1%204.png",
      "people" : 12400,
      "free" : 4
},
```

I'm going to use the price in this part. I tried to make it using state `total`, but I think the way to make it is wrong. How can I get the sum? I'd appreciate it if you let me know thanks!

**CartAside:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrap = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  left: 900px;
  bottom: 260px;
`


function CartAside({InCart}) {

  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)
  setTotal(InCart.map((product)=>{
    return total += product.price
  }))

  return (
    <Wrap>
    <div id='Price1'> 
      <span id='Price11'>
        선택상품 금액 {total}
      </span>
    </div>
   </Wrap>
  )
}


export default CartAside;
```

below file is parent component

**RealCart:**

```
import CartAside from './Components/CartAside';

function RealCart({InCart}) {

  return (
    <div>
      <Top />
      <Navi />
      <Cart />
      <CartHeader />
      {InCart.map((cart)=> {
        return <CartContent key={`key-${cart.id}`} cart={cart}/>
      })}
      <CartAside InCart={InCart}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RealCart;
```

and this is top component.I upload it just in case

**App.js:**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Site from './Site/Site';
import Login from './Site/Login/Login';
import SiteHomepage from './SiteHomepage/SiteHomepage';
import LecturePrecise from './LecturePrecise/LecturePrecise';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Login1 from './SiteHomepage/Login/Login1';
import { useState } from 'react';
import RealCart from './RealCart/RealCart';


function App() {

  
  const [Inproducts,setInproducts] = useState([])
  const [InCart, setInCart] = useState([]);

  // const loginButton = useSelector(state => state.loginClick.isClick);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* {loginButton&&<Login1 />} */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/realCart' element={<RealCart InCart={InCart} setInCart={setInCart}/>} />
        <Route path='/loginHome' element={<Site InCart={InCart} setInCart={setInCart} Inproducts={Inproducts} setInproducts={setInproducts}/>}/>
        <Route path='/' element={<SiteHomepage />} />
        <Route path='/lecturePrecise/:id' element={<LecturePrecise/>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I made map function in the file below

**Section5Bottom.jsx:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import "../section5.css";
import Section5Card from './Section5Card';


function Section5Bottom({Inproducts, setInproducts, InCart, setInCart}) {

  
  useEffect (()=> {
    axios.get("/data/products.json").then((data)=>{
      setInproducts(data.data.products);
    });
  },[setInproducts]);

  return (
    <div id='Section5Bottom'>
      {
        Inproducts.map((product)=>{
          return <Section5Card key={`key-${product.id}`} product={product} InCart={InCart} setInCart={setInCart}/>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Section5Bottom;
```

I made the array change when I click the cart icon in this file

**Section5Card.jsx:**

```
import '../section5.css';
import {FaCartPlus} from 'react-icons/fa';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import './card.css';

function Section5Card({product, InCart, setInCart}) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleCart = () => {
    const cartItem = {
      id : product.id,
      image : product.image,
      provider : product.provider,
      price : product.price,
      name : product.name
    }
    setInCart([...InCart, cartItem])
  }



  return (
   <div>
    <div id='CardWrap'>
          <div>
            <img id='Section5CardImg' src={product.image} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <FaCartPlus size='20' style={{color:'black', position:'relative', top:'124px', left:'130px', cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={()=>{dispatch({type:"ADD"}); handleCart()}} />
          </div>        
          <div id='CardBot'>
            <div id='CardBotBPrice'>
              ₩{product.price}
            </div>
            <div id='CardBotTag'>
              {product.people?
              <span id='CardBotTagPeople'>
                {product.people}명
              </span>:
              <>
                <span id='CardBotTagSale'>
                  {product.sale}
                </span>
              </>}            
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>  
   </div>
  )
}

export default Section5Card;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to define another method for this using `Array.prototype.reduce()` method. And since you need to update the total if your cart gets updated you need to use the `useEffect` with `InCart` as a dependency array.

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrap = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  left: 900px;
  bottom: 260px;
`

function CartAside({InCart}) {
  
  const total = useMemo(() => {
    return calculateTotal(InCart);
  }, [InCart])

  
  const calculateTotal = (cartItems) => {
    if(cartItems) {
      return cartItems.reduce((acc, obj) => {
       return acc + obj.price;
     }, 0)
    }else {
      return 0;
    }
  }


  return (
    <Wrap>
    <div id='Price1'> 
      <span id='Price11'>
        선택상품 금액 {total}
      </span>
    </div>
   </Wrap>
  )
}


export default CartAside;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')`
error occured. which part is wrong?

Comment: It's probably because InCart is undefined at the initial rendering, I have updated the answer with undefined check.

Comment: Now the error has been resolved and the screen comes out well. But I'm really sorry, but even if I put the item in the cart, the price continues to be 0

Comment: Can you post the code of the parent component that you are using this `CartAside` component.

Comment: In `RealCart` component how do you passed the updated cart values. Can you post that too? Ah sorry you have already added that. But I don't see any place that you are using `setInCart` to update the cart values.

Comment: I posted Section5Card.jsx and Section5Bottom.jsx codes.  There are a lot of props connections in the middle, but I just connected them, so I think these two files will be enough. Thank you so much for your hard work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249093/discussion-between-dulaj-ariyaratne-and-montakr).

Comment: I have updated the answer using useMemo instead of useEffect, it will reduce the re-rendering.